# Прозрачный background html

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне поместить png картинку на background с цветом?
Я имею следующий блок:

HTML file

```
<div class="main">
    <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

CSS file

```
.main {
   background: #2D66EE;
}

.main:before {
   background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/Ia1NuGb.png")
   opacaty: 0.6
}
```

Но почему-то мою картинку вообще не видно. Как думаете, в чём проблема?
Я буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: Потому что нет свойства `content`, как минимум + нужно как-то спозиционировать псевдоэлемент. Нет `;` после `background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/Ia1NuGb.png")` и `opacity` а не `opacaty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из способов как это сделать:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #DD66EE;
}

.main:before {
  content:"";
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/King_of_hearts_en.svg/150px-King_of_hearts_en.svg.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: .6;
  width: 170px;
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```